# Pandas, buscar en datraframe donde una de sus columnas los valores son listas

Tags: python, pandas, conjuntos

Hola tengo un df con dos columnas donde  "Lista_IRFIM" son listas, y necesito poder leer el valor del la columna "CelName" para saber si la columna "Lista_IRFIM, cumple cierta condicion y crear una nueva columna con True/False.

adjunto planilla con df : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W65-KdZhkchID9zO1QqzezA-7J3Llx1W/view?usp=sharing

El dataframe es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo  estas 4 listas(L/M/N/F) que son contra las que tengo que comparar la columna "Lista_IRFIM" si su valor contiene los mismos elementos que una de las 4 listas(L/M/N/F) segun criterio leido en la columna "CelName".

L = ['IRFIM-1', 'IRFIM-3', 'IRFIM-4']

N = ['IRFIM-2', 'IRFIM-3', 'IRFIM-4']

M = ['IRFIM-1', 'IRFIM-2', 'IRFIM-4']

F = ['IRFIM-1', 'IRFIM-2', 'IRFIM-3']

Ahora la columna "CelName" donde solo leo sus ultimos 3 caracateres con df['CelName'].str[-3:] entonces solo leo F11,F12,F13,L11,L12 etc... y aqui tengo que aplicar un criterio donde los valores que leo como por ejemplo F11/F12/F13, entonces verifico si su valor en la columna "Lista_IRFIM" son iguales o no a los contenidos de la lista F y asi sucesivamente para los demas  valores, o sea, L11/L12/L13 verifo su valor con lista L, luego crear una nueva columna que me diga True/False  segun corresponda.

Lo que necesito seria poder lograr esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

desde ya muchas gracias, saludos...

Agrego mas detalle:

La función me da False en todos los casos, revise realizando un debugging y veo lo siguiente recorriendo la función:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Toma la línea de la columna como una  Lista de modo que cuando compara siempre me da False.
Para mas información el df que adjunte, lo conforme desde el siguiente DataFrame dfIR y el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
group = dfIR.groupby('CelName')
df = group.apply(lambda x: 
x['IRFIM'].unique()).apply(list).reset_index(name='Lista_IRFIM')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo primero decir que lo que contiene la columna "Lista_IRFIM" no son en realidad listas, sino cadenas de caracteres. Es decir, aunque el dataframe no lo muestra, todo lo que hay en cada celda "va entre comillas" por así decir.

No obstante, si las "listas" contra las que te quieres comparar las convertimos también en cadenas no debería haber problema, pues podríamos comparar por ejemplo:

```
df.iloc[1, 1] == "['IRFIM-1', 'IRFIM-2', 'IRFIM-3']"
```

y nos daría `True`.

No obstante esta comparación es un poco "frágil", pues depende de que las cadenas `'IRFIM-1'` etc que aparecen dentro de la cadena usen también comillas simples y aparezcan en el mismo orden, sin espacios alrededor, con un solo espacio tras la coma, etc.

De todas formas parece que ese es el caso, y el siguiente código por tanto haría lo que pides:

```
listas = {
"L": ['IRFIM-1', 'IRFIM-3', 'IRFIM-4'],
"N": ['IRFIM-2', 'IRFIM-3', 'IRFIM-4'],
"M": ['IRFIM-1', 'IRFIM-2', 'IRFIM-4'],
"F": ['IRFIM-1', 'IRFIM-2', 'IRFIM-3']
}

def verificar(fila):
  letra = fila.CelName[-3]
  return str(listas[letra]) == fila.iloc[1]

df.apply(verificar, axis=1)
```

El truco como ves es aplicar la función `verificar` a cada una de las filas (gracias al parámetro `axis=1`, de lo contrario se aplicaría a cada columna). La función `verificar` recibe una fila y debe retornar `True` o `False` según corresponda. Lo primero que hacemos es sacar la letra F, M, N... de la posicion -3 de CellName. Usamos esa letra como clave para un diccionario que preparé previamente y contiene las listas contra las que queremos compararnos. Y finalmente comparamos esa lista (convertida en cadena) con el contenido de la columna 1 (`.icol[1]`). He decidido acceder a la columna por su número en vez de por su nombre, porque en el nombre había un montón de espacios.

El resultado de `df.apply()` es una nueva Serie de booleanos. Puedes asignarla a una nueva columna del dataframe:

```
df["Ok/Fail"] = df.apply(verificar, axis=1)
```

Resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

### Actualización

Parece que el dataframe con que trabaja el OP no es exactamente igual al xlsx que enlazó desde su pregunta, sino uno en el que realmente los contenidos de la columna sí son listas en vez de cadenas que contienen listas.

En ese caso debería bastar con cambiar la condición dentro de `validar()` para quitarle el `str()`.

No obstante la comparación puede seguir dando `False` si las listas no están *exactamente en el mismo orden*. Para evitar ese problema se pueden convertir a conjuntos antes de la comparación. Es decir:

```
def verificar(fila):
  letra = fila.CelName[-3]
  return set(listas[letra]) == set(fila.iloc[1])
```

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta @abulafia, edite mi consulta con mas detalles, porque me da False en todas las filas, veo que toma los valores de  la columna "Lista_ IRFIM" como clase-Lista. gracias desde ya por tu tiempo, saludos.

Comment: Mira a ver si lo que puse en la actualización te sirve. No entiendo por qué no te funcionó el quitar simplemente el `str()`.

Comment: Muchas gracias @abulafia excelente lo suyo como siempre! quedo solucionado el tema! estuve 2 días investigando, probando hasta que me rendi y realice esta consulta... gracias por su tiempo y paciencia, saludos